# Remove port at URL in my web

Tags: php, apache, laravel, port, laravel-3

I have a web hosted in hostingflame and all the code generates the URL with a :82 at the end, everything works fine but I have to give my domain with the :82 at the end. The application is on Laravel 3 so I can change the config file for the URL, but when I give a URL to the system everything works fine except the sessions don't work so nobody can log to the page.

Any idea of how to get rid of the :82?

The page: http://peliculasmonkey.com:82.

Comment: rtrim function maybe ?

Comment: "all the code generates the url with a :82 at the end" - can you show us the code that does that? If this is a Laravel application, it'll be quite recently written - is there some docs you can consult, or can you speak to the original developer? Edit: if changing a config file fixes the problem but introduces a new one, then debug the new problem?

Comment: I didn't think that the rtrim could work but it did, thankyou Maximus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your webhosting on port 82 you can't just remove it. Default http server port is 80 if you want to access your site without writing :82 you must change the service port, so you have to ask your hosting provider to change it. If you are your own hosting provider you must change your apache (or the webserver software you are using) port.

Comment: I am using the rtrim but the best solution its changing the service port, i already make the request of the change to the host.

Comment: The ONLY solution is to change the port. There is no other way. Well, there is anotherone...you have to ask every browser company (google, mozilla, apple, opera, etc) to change the default domain port to 82 xDDD so any other website must have :80 to work :p